# A tighter bound on Chebychev inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

How can we prove that if $X$ is a random variable with mean $0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$, then $$Pr[X \ge a] \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + a^2}$$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: See [this link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113972/cantellis-inequality-proof) for a proof of the inequality.

Comment: @ckoe thanks for the help!!